# purrr::map() - reading files in groups

Tags: r, purrr

I need to read a bunch of files from a grouped list, and combine them based on the group (files from the same group will have the same columns and thus can be reduced with `bind_rows()`.

I can't seem to get a handle on how the data is changing as I move through the `purrr::map()` function as I keep geting warnings that I can't use the `$` on atomic vectors.

The first thing I do is split by the group so that I get a list of a list of the files I want to read within each group.  Then I use map to go through each item in that list, and a second map to go through the rows on each sublist to read the files.  However something happens at that level where it no longer treats the data the same as if I was just working with a single group at the top level.

(The lack of being able to debug and look at my environment inside a map function is really an issue in understanding the mechanics.)

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse

x <- structure(list(survey = c("adm2014", "adm2015", "adm2016", "eap2008", 
                          "eap2009", "eap2011", "eap2012", "eap2013", "eap2014", "eap2015", 
                          "eap2016", "ef2008a", "ef2008b", "ef2008c", "ef2008cp", "ef2008d", 
                          "ef2009a", "ef2009b", "ef2009c", "ef2009d", "ef2010a", "ef2010b", 
                          "ef2010c", "ef2010cp", "ef2010d", "ef2011a", "ef2011b", "ef2011c", 
                          "ef2011d", "ef2012a", "ef2012b", "ef2012c", "ef2012cp", "ef2012d", 
                          "ef2013a", "ef2013b", "ef2013c", "ef2013d", "ef2014a", "ef2014b", 
                          "ef2014c", "ef2014cp", "ef2014d", "ef2015a", "ef2015b", "ef2015c", 
                          "ef2015d", "ef2016a", "ef2016b", "ef2016c", "ef2016cp", "ef2016d", 
                          "efest2008", "efest2009", "effy2008", "effy2009", "effy2010", 
                          "effy2011", "effy2012", "effy2013", "effy2014", "effy2015", "effy2016", 
                          "effy2017", "efia2008", "efia2009", "efia2011", "efia2012", "efia2013", 
                          "efia2014", "efia2015", "efia2016", "efia2017", "f0708_f1a", 
                          "f0708_f2", "f0708_f3", "f0809_f1a", "f0809_f2", "f0809_f3", 
                          "f0910_f1a", "f0910_f2", "f0910_f3", "f1011_f1a", "f1011_f2", 
                          "f1011_f3", "f1112_f1a", "f1112_f2", "f1112_f3", "f1213_f1a", 
                          "f1213_f2", "f1213_f3", "f1314_f1a", "f1314_f2", "f1314_f3", 
                          "f1415_f1a", "f1415_f2", "f1415_f3", "f1516_f1a", "f1516_f2", 
                          "f1516_f3", "gr2008", "gr2008_l2", "gr2009", "gr2009_l2", "gr200_08", 
                          "gr200_09", "gr200_10", "gr200_11", "gr200_12", "gr200_13", "gr200_14", 
                          "gr200_15", "gr200_16", "gr2010", "gr2010_l2", "gr2011", "gr2011_l2", 
                          "gr2012", "gr2012_l2", "gr2013", "gr2013_l2", "gr2014", "gr2014_l2", 
                          "gr2015", "gr2015_l2", "gr2016", "gr2016_l2", "hd2008", "hd2009", 
                          "hd2010", "hd2011", "hd2012", "hd2013", "hd2014", "hd2015", "hd2017", 
                          "ic2008", "ic2008_ay", "ic2008_py", "ic2009", "ic2009_ay", "ic2009_py", 
                          "ic2010", "ic2010_ay", "ic2010_py", "ic2011", "ic2011_ay", "ic2011_py", 
                          "ic2012", "ic2012_ay", "ic2012_py", "ic2013", "ic2013_ay", "ic2013_py", 
                          "ic2014", "ic2014_ay", "ic2014_py", "ic2015", "ic2015_ay", "ic2015_py", 
                          "ic2016", "ic2016_ay", "ic2016_py", "ic2017", "ic2017_ay", "ic2017_py", 
                          "s2008_abd", "s2008_cn", "s2008_f", "s2008_g", "s2009_abd", "s2009_cn", 
                          "s2009_f", "s2009_g", "s2010_abd", "s2010_cn", "s2010_f", "s2010_g", 
                          "s2011_abd", "s2011_cn", "s2011_f", "s2011_g", "sal2008_a", "sal2008_a_lt9", 
                          "sal2008_b", "sal2008_faculty", "sal2009_a", "sal2009_a_lt9", 
                          "sal2009_b", "sal2009_faculty", "sal2010_a", "sal2010_a_lt9", 
                          "sal2010_b", "sal2010_faculty", "sal2011_a", "sal2011_a_lt9", 
                          "sal2011_faculty"), survgroup = c("adm", "adm", "adm", "eap", 
                                                            "eap", "eap", "eap", "eap", "eap", "eap", "eap", "efa", "efb", 
                                                            "efc", "efcp", "efd", "efa", "efb", "efc", "efd", "efa", "efb", 
                                                            "efc", "efcp", "efd", "efa", "efb", "efc", "efd", "efa", "efb", 
                                                            "efc", "efcp", "efd", "efa", "efb", "efc", "efd", "efa", "efb", 
                                                            "efc", "efcp", "efd", "efa", "efb", "efc", "efd", "efa", "efb", 
                                                            "efc", "efcp", "efd", "efest", "efest", "effy", "effy", "effy", 
                                                            "effy", "effy", "effy", "effy", "effy", "effy", "effy", "efia", 
                                                            "efia", "efia", "efia", "efia", "efia", "efia", "efia", "efia", 
                                                            "f_f1a", "f_f2", "f_f3", "f_f1a", "f_f2", "f_f3", "f_f1a", "f_f2", 
                                                            "f_f3", "f_f1a", "f_f2", "f_f3", "f_f1a", "f_f2", "f_f3", "f_f1a", 
                                                            "f_f2", "f_f3", "f_f1a", "f_f2", "f_f3", "f_f1a", "f_f2", "f_f3", 
                                                            "f_f1a", "f_f2", "f_f3", "gr", "gr_l2", "gr", "gr_l2", "gr_08", 
                                                            "gr_09", "gr_10", "gr_11", "gr_12", "gr_13", "gr_14", "gr_15", 
                                                            "gr_16", "gr", "gr_l2", "gr", "gr_l2", "gr", "gr_l2", "gr", "gr_l2", 
                                                            "gr", "gr_l2", "gr", "gr_l2", "gr", "gr_l2", "hd", "hd", "hd", 
                                                            "hd", "hd", "hd", "hd", "hd", "hd", "ic", "ic_ay", "ic_py", "ic", 
                                                            "ic_ay", "ic_py", "ic", "ic_ay", "ic_py", "ic", "ic_ay", "ic_py", 
                                                            "ic", "ic_ay", "ic_py", "ic", "ic_ay", "ic_py", "ic", "ic_ay", 
                                                            "ic_py", "ic", "ic_ay", "ic_py", "ic", "ic_ay", "ic_py", "ic", 
                                                            "ic_ay", "ic_py", "s_abd", "s_cn", "s_f", "s_g", "s_abd", "s_cn", 
                                                            "s_f", "s_g", "s_abd", "s_cn", "s_f", "s_g", "s_abd", "s_cn", 
                                                            "s_f", "s_g", "sal_a", "sal_a_lt9", "sal_b", "sal_faculty", "sal_a", 
                                                            "sal_a_lt9", "sal_b", "sal_faculty", "sal_a", "sal_a_lt9", "sal_b", 
                                                            "sal_faculty", "sal_a", "sal_a_lt9", "sal_faculty")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                            "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -197L))

x %>% 
  split(.$survgroup) %>% 
  map(function(currentgroup) {
    #currentgroup should now be a tibble of each group.
    currentgroup %>% 
      map(function(singlesurvey) { #singlesurvey should be each row in the group
        x <- read_csv(path_expand(paste0("~data/IPEDS/API Pulls/datadownloaded/", singlesurvey$survey, ".csv")))
    }) %>% bind_rows()

  })
#> Error in path_expand(paste0("~data/IPEDS/API Pulls/datadownloaded/", singlesurvey$survey, : could not find function "path_expand"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: `path.expand` instead of `path_expand` maybe?

Comment: from package `fs`: path_expand() differs from base::path.expand() in the interpretation of the home directory of Windows. In particular path_expand() uses the path set in the USERPROFILE environment variable and, if unset, then uses HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH.

Comment: Interesting! A smarter file/path management  ... Definitely will check this package out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that we need to loop through the individual files in the column instead of the looping through the columns in the dataset.  In the OP's post, the second `map` loops through the `data.frame` with a single column.  Here, the basic unit is a `data.frame` with one column.  If the column was extracted as a `vector`, the unit becomes `vector` and it loops through each element of the `vector`

```
x %>% 
   split(.$survgroup) %>%
        map(~ .x %>%
                 pull(survey) %>%
                 map(~ .x %>% 
                    paste0("~data/IPEDS/API Pulls/datadownloaded/", ., '.csv') %>% 
                    path.expand %>% 
                    read_csv)))
```

Comment: this has 2 maps, same as mine.  The only different seems to be the pull to isolate the survey, however this doesn't work regardless:
> x %>% 
+   split(.$survgroup) %>%
+   map(~ .x %>%
+         pull(survey) %>%
+         map(~ .x %>% 
+               paste0("~data/IPEDS/API Pulls/datadownloaded/", .x, '.csv') %>% 
+               path.expand %>% 
+               read_csv))
Error: 'adm2014~data/IPEDS/API Pulls/datadownloaded/adm2014.csv' does not exist in current working directory

for some reason it puts teh survey value in front.  Trying to fix it back to my original...

Comment: but adding the pull gives bad results as well:

x %>% 
  split(.$survgroup) %>%
  map(~ .x %>%
        pull(survey) %>%
        map(function(dat) {
              read_csv(path_expand(paste0("~/Google Drive/SI/DataScience/data/gates/IPEDS/API Pulls/data/downloaded/", dat$survey, '.csv')))
          })
      )
#Error in dat$survey : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @jzadra  I think I made a mistake.  Sorry.  It should be `.` instead of `.x`

Comment: aha, got it.  Thanks

Comment: So I think the issue was not the number of maps I had, but rather that I was trying to pass my second map statement a multi-column tibble rather than a 1d list.  I have gotten around this by doing multiple pull statements to create multiple 1d lists and then using `pmap()`

Comment: @jzadra  Yeah, actually, I intended that, but somehow written wrongly.  Updated the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use list-columns to read the data frames into a column, and do the split afterwards.

```
x %>% 
  mutate(data = map(survey, ~ read_csv(path.expand(paste0("~data/IPEDS/API Pulls/datadownloaded/", .x, ".csv"))))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  split(.$survgroup)
```

Comment: The problem is that I actually have other functions that i need to do to within the lowest level map.

Comment: Could you add these to the question? You might be able to do these with list-columns and/or `group_by`

Comment: Unfortunately it's too much data to really do a reprex (pulling from multiple files to combine dictionaries with data in order to rename and recode).

Comment: Create a minimum reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve